# Power series in p-adic integers

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

How can we show that for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $\log_p(1+x)$ converges in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ when $|x|_p < 1$?

To clarify, $\log_p(1+x)$ is the power series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$

How can we show that $\exp_p(x)$ converges for: $|x|_p < p^\frac{-1}{p-1}$?  How can we approximate the largest power of $p$ dividing $n!$?

$$\exp_p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

I've shown that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n|_p = 0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_i$ converges.  How do I show the following:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}\right|_p = 0$$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|_p = 0$$
I know that:
$$\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|_p = p^\frac{n-S_n}{p-1}$$

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48620/11619).

Comment: What do you mean **a function** converges? Perhaps you meant some power series?

Comment: Yes, $\log_p(1+x)$ in its power series representation, as now described above

Comment: This is discussed in nearly every book on $p$-adic analysis.  Have you read about convergence of power series in any book on $p$-adics (Gouvea, Koblitz, Robert, ...)?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Yes, you really do have to read up on all of this. I would draw the Newton Polygon of the log. This tells you the convergence-radius, and tells you that there’s a zero with valuation $1/(p-1)$. Closer contemplation of the NP shows you that the inverse of log can not be convergent as far as $\{z: v(z)=1/(p-1)$. Then you notice that conjugating by the homothecy $z\mapsto p^{1/(p-1)}z$ turns the log into a series with all $p$-integral coeffs, so that it now has an inverse valid on the open disc. This shows that the exponential is convergent exactly for $v(z)<1/(p-1)$. No factorials need apply!