# $\exp(2)$ does not converge $2$-adically.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

We have $\exp(2)= \sum_{i=0}^n {\frac{2^n}{n!}}$.

I am trying to show that $\exp(2)$ does not converge $2$-adically.

i.e. I need to show $\nu_2 (\frac{2^n}{n!})$ does not tend to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$, where $\nu_p (x) = \max$ { $a : p^a $divides $x$ }.

$\nu_p (x)$ is $\infty$ only when $x$ is $0$.

However, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}=0$, I'll have $\nu_2 (\frac{2^n}{n!})\to \infty$ and hence $\exp(2)$ does converge $2$-adically, which is the exact opposite of what I'm trying to prove.

What went wrong there?

Comment: "$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}=0$" This is only true in real numbers. In $2$-adic numbers, this series doesn't converge (which is something you need to prove)

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $v(n!)$?

Comment: @Bruno Joyal: I know that $V_p(n!) = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^3} \right\rfloor$ and so on.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_exponential_function) or locally for example [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/48620/11619). The $p$-adic exponential series $\exp (x)$ converges only when $|x|_p<p^{-1/(p-1)}$. This follows from the formula for $\nu_p(n!)$ that you know. For large $n$ the r.h.s. is approximately $n/(p-1)$, so $x^n$ must be divisible by a power of $p$ that grows faster than $n/(p-1)$. Therefore $x$ needs to be divisible by a higher power than $p^{1/(p-1)}$. Those fractions come into play in extensions of the $p$-adic field.

Comment: If $\exp(2)$ converged in $\Bbb Q_2$, then there would be an element $\alpha\in\Bbb Q_2$  such that $\log\alpha=2$. There are such things in the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q_2$, in fact infinitely many of them, but none is in $\Bbb Q_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nu_{2}(\frac{2^{n}}{n!})$ does not go to infinity as n goes to infinity.  The function is unbounded, true, but it is not monotonically increasing with $n$.  It drops when $n$ hits a power of $2$ and gives you a lot of factors of $2$ in the factorial.  In fact $\nu_{2}(\frac{2^{n}}{n!})$ drops all the way down to $1$ when $n$ is a power of $2$.

The exponential function converges in $2$-adics when the argument is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Is there a direct way of showing $V_p(\frac{2^n}{n!})$ is 1 when n is a power of 2?

Comment: To figure out the V_2 function, you subtract the terminal 0's in n! from those in 2^n, both in base 2.  Other comments have given the formula for the terminal 0's in n!.  For 2^n you have just n terminal 0's.  Put in n = 2^m for any whole number m and find the difference.  You'll be amazed, I was.

Comment: I used the geometric series when $n=2^k$ and it all worked out fine! Thanks.